antd-select dropdown The select options located in the top left corner of the screen are not visible, on refresh page it get fixed. in windows pc only
using antd/dist/antd.css popover and select drop down open on left top of the page in windows pc
list of options open on left of dropdown menu in antd reactjs after reload page its come below the dropdown menu which is fine
  <div className="select-filter pt5 pb8">
                <Select
                  bordered={false}
                  customSelect={false}
                  showSearch
                  filterOption={(input, option: OptionsInterface) => option.label
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                  placeholder={t('common.filters.selectSubject')}
                  data={[
                    {
                      label: t('common.filters.selectSubject'),
                      value: '',
                      name: t('common.filters.selectSubject'),
                    },
                    ...(subjects ? subjects.map((subject) => ({
                      value: subject?.variant_subject_id ? subject.variant_subject_id?.join(',') : subject?.id.toString(),
                      name: subject?.name,
                      label: subject?.name,
                    })) : []),
                  ]}
                  value={filterValue?.subjectId}
                  onSelect={(value) => {
                    const subjectObj = subjectMapper[Number(value)];
                    if (subjectObj?.variant_subject_id) {
                      const variantSubject = subjectObj?.variant_subject_id?.join(',');
                      handleUpdateFilterState(variantSubject,
                        SUBJECT_ALLOCATION_CONSTANTS.SUBJECT_ID);
                    } else {
                      handleUpdateFilterState(String(value),
                        SUBJECT_ALLOCATION_CONSTANTS.SUBJECT_ID);
                    }
                    if (value) {
                      trackEvent({
                        eventType: CLICKSTREAM.EVENT_TYPES.COMMON,
                        allow: CLICKSTREAM.ALLOW,
                        name: CLICKSTREAM.EVENTS.SUBJECT_ALLOCATION.SELECT_SUBJECT_FILTER.NAME,
                        props: {
                          subject: subjects?.filter((sub) => {
                            if (sub?.variant_subject_id) {
                              return sub?.variant_subject_id?.join(',') === value?.toString();
                            }
                            return sub?.id?.toString() === value?.toString();
                          })[0]?.name || '',
                        },
                      });
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </div>


Please use platforms to generate a fiddle (like JSFiddle) to provide a better question.
